# 502 bad gateway error on nginx server when using flask restplus

Tags: python, nginx, flask, uwsgi, flask-restplus

This error occurs for me solely when using flask restplus with an nginx server. The server works correctly when just flask is used and the flask-restplus api works fine when running the app locally or even with:

```
uwsgi --socket 0.0.0.0:5000 --protocol=http -w wsgi:application
```

on my EC2 instance.

I have tried using gunicorn along side nginx (rather than uwsgi) but I get the same error in my /var/log/nginx/error.log file:

```
2017/07/03 20:30:02 [crit] 957#957: *1 connect() to unix:/home/jamie/my_app/my_app.sock failed 
(2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream,
client: #.#.#.#, server: #.#.#.#, request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", upstream: 
"uwsgi://unix:/home/jamie/my_app/my_app.sock:", host: "#.#.#.#", referrer: "http://#.#.#.#/"
```

The app is envoked through a wsgi.py that looks like this:

```
from main import application

if __name__ == "__main__":
    application.run('0.0.0.0')
```

And the main.py file contains the following:

```
 from boto3 import resource
 from flask import json, request, abort
 from flask import Flask
 from flask_restplus import Api, Resource, fields

 application = Flask(__name__)
 api = Api(application)



@api.route('/users', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
class Users(Resource):
    def get(self):
        return users_get()

    @api.expect(resource_fields)
    def post(self):
         return user_login()


@api.route('/users/<string:Username>', methods=['GET', 'PUT', 'DELETE'])
class User(Resource):
    def get(self, Username):
         return user_get(Username)

    def put(self, Username):
        return create_user(Username)

    def delete(self, Username):
        return delete_user(Username)
```

In order to configure the server I followed [this digitalocean tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-flask-applications-with-uwsgi-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-16-04) and my config is essentially the same. If anyone wants to see it I can provide it.

My uwsgi ini file is as follows:

```
[uwsgi]
module = wsgi:application

master = true
processes = 5
socket = my_app.sock
chmod-socket = 666
vacuum = true

die-on-term = true
```

My nginx sever config is at etc/nginx/sites-available/my_app
 like so:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name #.#.#.#;

    location / {
        include uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_pass unix:/home/jamie/my_app/my_app.sock;
    }
}
```

And finally my /etc/systemd/system/fitness_test_app.service file is like so:

```
[Unit]
Description=uWSGI instance to serve my_app
After=network.target

[Service]
User=jamie
Group=www-data
WorkingDirectory=/home/jamie/my_app
Environment="PATH=/home/jamie/my_app/myprojectenv/bin"
ExecStart=/home/jamie/my_app/myprojectenv/bin/uwsgi --ini my_app.ini

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

If anyone has any idea what could cause this problem an answer would be greatly appreciated as I have been unable to solve this issue for some time.

Comment: Have you tried toggling the debug option? It might show you a bit more information.

    if __name__ == "__main__":
        application.run(host="0.0.0.0", debug=True)

Comment: Could you post the nginx virtual host configuration? If you have follow digitalocean tutorial, most probably is the the file in the folder /etc/nginx/sites-available/.

Comment: Sure @JavierLopez. I will add it to the original post

Comment: Look for my_app.sock file with "find /home/jamie/my_app/ name my_app.sock" to check it is where you set in the virtual host.